# Disable Toggle to Classic | Automate permission assignment to New Users Analysis for Implementation

Tags: profile, permission-sets

When a new user is created in Salesforce and is assigned to lightning enabled profile, then they should be automatically assigned the existing permission set "Restrict Toggle to Classic".

Users assigned to the below profiles should not have the ability to toggle back to classic.

AS CSA

AS NCSP Coordinator

AS Implementation Team

AS NCSP CSA

AS NCSP Management

Contract Admin NA

IM_Read Only

IM_Standard Platform User

NAS Knowledge Manager

NAS Support Agent

NAS Support Manager

NAS Support Manager TCOP

IM_Bouldlogic_Marketing

IM_Channel Manager

IM_Executive

IM_Executive - Limited

IM_Government Services

IM_Marketing

IM_Marketing Dashboard Admin

IM_Proposal_Services

IM_Read Only Minus View Setup and Config

IM_Read_Only_Except_Cases

IM Sales Kimble

IM Sales Support

IMAP Manager

IME Contracts

IME Marketing

IME Manager Kimble

IME Sales Support

IME SC Account Admin

IMLA Marketing

IMLA Sales AM

IMLA Sales Support

Legal

IM_Commissions

IM Product Manager

IM Sales Ops

IM Sales Ops Super User

IM Sales eSignature

IMAP in Country Admin

IMAP Read Only

IMAP Sales AM

IME_Manager

IME Read Only

IME Read Only with Reporting

IME Sales AM2

IME SUper User

IMLA In Country Admin

IMLA Manager

IM_Sales

IMLA Custom Sys Admin

IME_SC_Account_Admin

IME_Sales_AM

---

Solution =
Development Steps:
Step 1: Create a Permission Set
Before we begin on a solution for this use case, check out the Restrict Toggle to Classic on how to set it up.

1. Click Setup.
2. In the Quick Find box, type Permission Sets.
3. Select Permission Sets, then click New.
4. Label the Permission Set then press the tab key, the API Name will auto-populate.
5. Click Save.

---

Step 2.1: Salesforce Flow – Define Flow Properties
As we have a requirement of creating a related record (PermissionSetAssignment), this is why we have to use After Save flow.
1.

1. Click Setup.
2. In the Quick Find box, type Flows.
3. Select Flows then click on the New Flows.
4. Select the Record-Triggered Flow option and click on Next and configure the flow as follows:
   How do you want to start building: Freeform
   Trigger the Flow When: A record is created
   Run Flow: After the record is saved
   Object: User
5. Select Custom condition logic is met.
6. Set Conditions
   Row 1
   Field: User | IsActive
   Operator: Equals
   Value: {!$GlobalConstant.True}
   Row 2, 3, 4 …
   Field: User | ProfileID
   Operator: Equals
   Value: 00e80000001OHLSAA4, 00e80000001OHLZAA4, 00e80000001OHLUAA4

### Click Done.

Step 2.2: Salesforce Flow – Adding a Get Record Element to Find Permission Set Id
The next step is to find the permissions set Restrict Toggle to Classic Id. To do that follow the below instructions:

1. Under Toolbox, select Element.
2. Drag-and-drop Get Records element onto the Flow designer.
3. Enter a name in the Label field; the API Name will auto-populate.
4. Select the Permission Set object from the dropdown list.
5. Select All Conditions Are Met (AND).
6. Set Filter Conditions
   Row 1:
   Field: Label
   Operator: Equals
   Value: Restrict Toggle to Classic
7. How Many Records to Store:
   select Only the first record
8. How to Store Record Data:
   Choose the option to Automatically store all fields.
9. Click Done.

---

Step 2.3: Salesforce Flow – Create Records – Add Permission Set Id to New Users
The next step is to add Permission Sets to New Users. We will use the Create Records element. To do this, drag-and-drop the Create Records element onto the flow designer and map the fields according to the details below:

1. Under Toolbox, select Elements. Drag and drop Create Records onto the canvas.
2. Input the following information:
   Enter Label the API Name will auto-populate.
   How Many Records to Create: One
3. How to Set the Record Fields: Use separate resources, and literal values
4. Object: PermissionSetAssignment
5. Set Field Values for the Permission Set Assignment
6. Row 1:
   Field: AssigneeId
   Value: {!$Record.Id}
7. Click Add Row
8. Row 2:
   Field: PermissionSetId
   Value: {!Find_Permission_Set_Id.Id}
   Click Done.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] of this site and visit [ask].

Comment: Hi Team, Thanks for the suggestions... I was a new member in our stack Exchange...I was not aware of the rules and regulations so kept question. I have added the solution steps into this question itself. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lex_enable_users_disable_switcher.htm&type=5), you can enable the permission at profile level (see screenshot below).

> Or, enable the permission in a custom profile to remove the Switcher
> from everyone in that profile.

[image]

Since, all the profiles you have listed seem to be custom profiles, I guess its best you enable this permission at profile level, instead of trying to automate via permission set assignment. You can find this permission in the `System Permissions` section in the profile.

Comment: Thanks, arut thanks for your valuable input, but our customer needs to do automate this process as per the above-mentioned requirements. Could you please suggest.

Comment: Why is this approach not acceptable? You will achieve the same end result thru this approach. If you must absolutely go with permission set assignment, you can either write a trigger on User object (or create record triggered flow) and conditionally insert record into `PermissionSetAssignment` object. For example, look at this approach given in this [blog](https://automationchampion.com/2020/11/26/automatically-add-permission-sets-to-new-user/). Something similar can be done.

Comment: Thanks, arut  for your kind response,  I have written a trigger and calling custom metadata types into triggers with above mentioned profiles and its working fine but our customer want to automate by using flow. I have created a custom metadata types and trying to call into flow but no luck. Can you please help me with the steps of flow so I will automate this process by using Flow.

Comment: Hi @arut, I have added the solution steps into this question itself.  thanks !